# Full outer join on full column list first, otherwise partial column list

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to know whether I could perform a full outer join between two tables on a full column list first, and if this fails, a partial column list.
For example:

```
Table A
|  a  |  b  |  c  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  x  |  y  |  z  |
|  q  |  r  |  s  |


Table B
|  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |  e  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  q  |  r  |  s  |  t  |  u  |
|  q  |  r  |     |  x  |  y  |
|     |     |     |  x  |  y  |

Failed query:
SELECT *
FROM A FULL OUTER JOIN B
ON
 (A.a = B.a AND A.b = B.b AND A.c = B.c)
 OR (A.a = B.a AND A.b = B.b)

Desired result
|  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |  e  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  x  |  y  |  z  |     |     |
|  q  |  r  |  s  |  t  |  u  |
|  q  |  r  |     |  x  |  y  |
|     |     |     |  x  |  y  |
```

I am using Postgresql. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query would produce the desired result exactly:

```
SELECT *
FROM   A
FULL   JOIN B USING (a,b,c)
ORDER  BY a DESC NULLS LAST;
```

But I am not entirely convinced that your example fits your description - which leaves room for interpretation.

Comment: Thanks Erwin. After rethinking my example, I realised my problem was not on the join, but how I queried the joined result. My error: SELECT A.a, A.b, A.c, B.d, B.e; Instead of: SELECT a,b,c,d,e.